# How to throw $n$ random noodles of equal length?

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics, random, geometry

I've been meaning to modify some code given in the the [Region Disjoint documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionDisjoint.html) for the [Buffon's Needle problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffon%27s_needle_problem) to instead model [*Buffon's Noodle Problem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffon%27s_noodle).

In Buffon's *Needle* problem you randomly toss $n$ straight lines (i.e. needles) of length $l$ in between parallel lines of width $t$. The probability that the needle lies across a line is given by,
$${\displaystyle p={\frac {2}{\pi }}{\frac {l}{t}}.}$$

In Buffon's *Noodle* problem you instead randomly toss $n$ rigid plane curves (i.e. noodles) of length $l$ in between parallel lines of width $t$ and the probability is the same.

My question is, **how can I modify the code shown below to throw $n$ noodles instead of needles?**

**Input:**

```
d = 0.2; n = 1000;
lines = MeshRegion[
Join @@ Table[{{-1 - d, y}, {1 + d, y}}, {y, -1 - d, 1 + d, d}], 
Line[Partition[Range[2 Floor[2/d + 3]], 2]]];
needles =  Table[Line[{pt, RandomPoint[Circle[pt, d]]}], {pt, RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n,2}]}];
overlap = Select[needles, ! RegionDisjoint[lines, #] &];
Show[lines, Graphics[{Red, overlap, Black, Complement[needles, overlap]}]]
N[(2 n)/Length[overlap]]
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: What's your distribution of shapes of your noodles?  (You simply cannot solve the problem without such knowledge.)

Comment: The noodles can be any rigid plane curve. So every separate noodle can be any random curve (as long as their arc length is equal). It really would be akin to throwing noodles on a table.

Comment: "Any random curve" is meaningless.  You simply *must* state a distribution, otherwise the problem is unsolvable.  If all the noodles "happen" to be straight you'll get one answer;  if they "happen" to be wound into teeny spirals you'll get another;  if they...

Comment: The expected number of crossings does not depend on the shape of the noodles. The problem statement is exactly that it each of the noodles take the form of any possible rigid plane curve. This is written in the linked Wikipedia page. The only constraint is that each noodle must have the same arc length. I've seen it implemented in a Wolfram Demonstrations using truncated Bezier curves but it doesn't count the crossings. https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/TheBuffonNoodleProblem/

Comment: The demonstration you link to does count the number of crossings, and displays them.

Comment: Why do they have to be rigid? The physics of a thrown wet noodle is probably more interesting.

Comment: Yes Szabolcs but I'm not able to adjust the source code for what I wanted. It seems quite lengthy. I really wanted to have a simple function as in the post above which I can repeat a few times with Table and take a mean.

Comment: Daniel I suppose because a 3D wet noodle will affect the expectation of crossings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having given no indication of what kinds of noodles you're interested in - here's a quick hack to make a noodle that's easy to work with:

```
generateNoodle[l_, np_, cent_] := Block[{ls = l/np, pts},
  pts = RandomPoint[Circle[{0, 0}, ls], np];
  Line /@ Partition[(cent+#)&/@ Accumulate[pts],2,1]]
```

Just connect together `np` randomly oriented line segments of length `l/np` with the first segment beginning at `cent`.

Unlike needles, noodles can intersect a given line multiple times. So we need to change the `RegionDisjoint` to take into account multiple crossings. This is easy enough, just check each segment in the noodle. If you really want your noodle to be a smooth curve, more thought needs to be given here. Counting the number of points in `RegionIntersection` should work. Then we color red any noodle where at least one segment intersects a line and otherwise black. Finally we count the number of intersections and compare against theory.

```
d = 0.2; l = 0.1; n = 1000;
lines = MeshRegion[Join @@ Table[{{-1-d,y},{1+d,y}}, {y,-1-d,1+d,d}], 
   Line[Partition[Range[2 Floor[2/d+3]],2]]];
noodles = Table[generateNoodle[l,10,pt], {pt, RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, 2}]}];
ints = With[{nood = #}, RegionDisjoint[#, lines] & /@ nood] & /@ noodles;
overlap = Extract[noodles, Position[And @@ # & /@ ints, False]];
Show[lines,Graphics[{Red, overlap, Black, Complement[noodles, overlap]}]]
{N[Count[ints, False, 2]/n], 2. t/(\[Pi] d)}
```

Output: `{0.299, 0.31831}` - not too bad!

[image]

$l=1/2$, $np=15$, $n=1000\to$ theory $\approx 1.59$, exp $=1.53$

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I was pretty much looking for something like this. I suppose the only way to "solve" this problem is through what you call a quick hack, since there is no well defined shape for the noodle.

Answer (score 0):

```
randomNoodle[start_: {0, 0}, angle_: Pi/4, length_: 1, pieces_: 20] :=
  Line[AnglePath[start, Thread[{length/pieces, RandomReal[{-angle, angle}, pieces]}]]]
```

***Examples:***

```
SeedRandom[4444]
noodles = Table[randomNoodle[RandomReal[1, 2]], 20];

MinMax[ArcLength /@ noodles]
```

> ```
> {1., 1.}
> ```

```
g = Graphics[{RandomColor[], Thick, #} & /@ noodles, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

```
intersections = Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections[g];
Show[g, Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Point @ intersections}, 
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]